# Android notification bar background color

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change the background color of notification bar. I have changed colorPrimaryDark in colors.xml

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#333</color>
```

The problem is when i open my app the background color of notification bar becomes blue. And then (less then 1 sec) it gets #333.

I want it to be #333 as it starts.
How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Try to test it again. Clean the project, build and run it again

Comment: I have just created a new project with Empty Activity, changed colorPrimaryDark to #333 and "Run". Still the same thing happens. Notifications bar gets blue first, then it gets #333.